# Items in grid structure with arrows between items

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, draggable

I am trying to do a grid with drag and drop, similar to what can be offered by Muuri (https://haltu.github.io/muuri/), Draggable (https://shopify.github.io/draggable/), and many others.

My problem is that I want edges or arrow between the grid items. This can be obtained if I, instead of a grid, use a tool to draw network graphs (e.g. http://js.cytoscape.org/), but I don't want that much freedom in terms of where the items can be. I just want a simple 4 column with same-size items.

How can this be accomplished? Would it be possible to just use Muuri and then add elements on top of the items with `position: absolute` to reflect the arrows between the items?

Answer (score 0):

I think `position:absolute` works.

I just added "<" and ">" to the muuri demo. Make them absolutely positioned according to the card (draggable items)

[image]

This is the added css

```
.card-title::before {
    content: ">";
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.card-title::after {
    content: "<";
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.card-title {
    position: relative;
}
```